# Can't start openshot-qt

Tags: qt, openshot

System Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Have installed OpenShot through Synaptic and can't start it either though Main Menu or Terminal. Terminal answer like this:

````
Loaded modules from installed directory: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt
      launch:INFO ------------------------------------------------
      launch:INFO    OpenShot (version 2.4.1)
      launch:INFO ------------------------------------------------
         app:INFO openshot-qt version: 2.4.1
         app:INFO libopenshot version: 0.1.9
         app:INFO platform: Linux-4.15.0-108-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
         app:INFO processor: x86_64
         app:INFO machine: x86_64
         app:INFO python version: 3.6.9
         app:INFO qt5 version: 5.9.5
         app:INFO pyqt5 version: 5.10.1
   json_data:WARNING Couldn't load user settings file, no data.
         app:ERROR Couldn't load user settings. Exiting.
Couldn't load user settings file, no data.
moon@moon-server:~$ ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your user settings file

If you do a

```
rm -rf .openshot
```

from your users home it will remove all user settings and recreate default versions.

Do check if there is anything you want to preserve. Or make a backup with

```
tar cvfz openshot_backup.gz .openshot
```